# How to run maven wrapper from docker?

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile

I have to run a maven wrapper command from dockerfile but I don't know how can I do it?
When I tried wrote like this:

```
RUN ./mvnw -s settings.xml clean install
```

this command not work. I have error `mvnw: not found`

my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./

RUN ./mvnw -s .mvn/settings.xml -B -f /app/pom.xml dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:resolve dependency:go-offline
```

Comment: can you add your Dockerfile ?

Comment: @Nico I had just added my dockerfile.

Comment: Are you sur of the paths you use in your RUN command ? because /app/pom.xml should be ./pom.xml as you set WORKDIR /app

Answer (score 2):

I find the way how to fix this issue.
I had just added `chnod +x ./mvnw` command and final `RUN` command looks like this:

```
RUN chmod +x ./mvnw && \
./mvnw -s .mvn/settings.xml -B -f /app/pom.xml dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:resolve dependency:go-offline
```