# Spring Boot Docker -> Cannot run docker-compose up -d (RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve issue)

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose

I have a problem to run Spring Boot with Docker. When I run docker-compose.yml through this command docker-compose up -d, I get this issue shown below.

```
 => ERROR [build 4/6] RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve                                                                                                                                0.9s 
------
 > [build 4/6] RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve:
#0 0.230 /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./mvnw dependency:resolve]: exit code: 127
```

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the **Dockerfile** shown below

```
# Stage 1: Build stage
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim AS build

# Copy Maven files for dependency resolution
COPY pom.xml mvnw ./
COPY .mvn .mvn

# Resolve project dependencies
RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve

# Copy application source code
COPY src src

# Package the application
RUN ./mvnw package

# Stage 2: Run stage
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

# Set working directory
WORKDIR ays-be

# Copy the JAR file from the build stage
COPY --from=build target/*.jar /app/ays-be.jar

# Expose port 9790
EXPOSE 9790

# Set the entrypoint command for running the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/ays-be.jar"]
```

Here is the **docker-compose.yml** file shown below

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: ays-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ays
      MYSQL_USER: ays
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ayspass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ayspass
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - ays

  ays-be:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ays-be
    ports:
      - "9790:9790"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=development
      - AYS_DB_USERNAME=ays
      - AYS_DB_PASSWORD=ayspass
      - AYS_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/ays
    networks:
      - ays


# Volumes
volumes:
  db-data:

networks:
  ays:
```

Comment: What's the `mvnw` file in `COPY pom.xml mvnw ./`? Usually it's just `mvn`.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I use default mvnw file produced by Spring Boot.

Comment: Some typical things to check here: is the `mvnw` script executable?  Does it have Unix line endings?  The very first line of the script should name an interpreter, does that interpreter exist in the base image?

Comment: @DavidMaze I also add `RUN chmod +x mvnw` before `RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve` but nothing changed. I still get the same error.

Comment: [Dockerfile's `COPY` doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) doesn't mention the _current dir_ `./...` syntax. Also, ["_The default working directory for running binaries within a container is the root directory (`/`)._"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir). What if you try it without the _current dir_ `.`?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Which line should I revise it?

Comment: I'd try it in the first `COPY` and the two `RUN`  lines.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I revised `COPY pom.xml mvnw /` , `RUN /mvnw dependency:resolve` and `RUN /mvnw package` but nothing changed. I still get the same issue.

Comment: Perhaps [How to run maven wrapper from docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58409132/1744774) helps.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I also tried to add `chnod +x ./mvnw` but I still get the same issue

Comment: Mmmh, I tried it with `COPY pom.xml mvnw /`, `RUN /mvnw dependency:resolve` and `RUN /mvnw package` here now and it worked.

Comment: This is weird. First I got the same error as you. Then I removed the `.`s and it worked. Now I added them again and it still works.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I still couldn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the **answer** shown below

1 ) Use `maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim` to detect Maven instead of openjdk:17-jdk-slim for building stage.

2 ) Revise the part of `Copy Maven files for dependency resolution`

2 ) Change `Resolve project dependencies` and `Package the application` to `Build the project and create the executable JAR`

Here is the updated Dockerfile shown below

```
# Stage 1: Build stage
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim AS build

# Copy Maven files for dependency resolution
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY .mvn .mvn

# Copy application source code
COPY src src

# Build the project and create the executable JAR
RUN mvn clean install

# Stage 2: Run stage
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

# Set working directory
WORKDIR ays-be

# Copy the JAR file from the build stage
COPY --from=build target/*.jar /app/ays-be.jar

# Expose port 9790
EXPOSE 9790

# Set the entrypoint command for running the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/ays-be.jar"]
```